# how to display database value using json encode in a tbody of table

Tags: php, jquery, json, html-table, display

I am trying to display database values using JSON encoding, but I don't know how to display it in the table that I have set up in my HTML form. Anyone know how to do it? I would appreciate if you give me an example.

This is my table and my PHP function.

```js
<?php 

  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // Example php script for fetching data from mysql database
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $host = "localhost";
  $user = "root";
  $pass = "";

  $databaseName = "silo";
  $tableName = "temp1";

  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // 1) Connect to mysql database
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------

  $con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
  $dbs = mysql_select_db($databaseName, $con);

  $tanggal=$_POST['datepicker'];
  $silo=$_POST['silo'];
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // 2) Query database for data
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tableName");          //query
  $array = mysql_fetch_row($result);                          //fetch result 

  if($array>0){
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    }   
 }else{
    echo "<li>Tidak ada artikel yang ditemukan <li>";
 }
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // 3) echo result as json 
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  echo json_encode($array);

?>
```

```html
<form name="table_s" id="table_s" class="table_s">
    <table id="table_s" class="table_s"cellspacing='0' class="js-serial" border="2">
        <thead>

      <tr>
                <th><center>No.</center></th>
                <th><center>S1</center></th>
                <th><center>S2</center></th>
                <th><center>S3</center></th>
                <th><center>S4</center></th>
                <th><center>S5</center></th>
                <th><center>S6</center></th>
                <th><center>S7</center></th>
                <th><center>S8</center></th>
                <th><center>S9</center></th>
                <th><center>S10</center></th>
                <th><center>S11</center></th>
                <th><center>S12</center></th>
                <th><center>Ambien</center></th>
                <th><center>Average</center></th>
                <th><center>Deff</center></th>
                <th><center>Status</center></th>
      </tr>

        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>

          <tr>
            <td id="td_s0"></td>
            <td id="td_s1"></td>
            <td id="td_s2"></td>
            <td id="td_s3"></td>
            <td id="td_s4"></td>
            <td id="td_s5"></td>
            <td id="td_s6"></td>
            <td id="td_s7"></td>
            <td id="td_s8"></td>
            <td id="td_s9"></td>
            <td id="td_s10"></td>
            <td id="td_s11"></td>
            <td id="td_s12"></td>
            <td id="td_s13"></td>
            <td id="td_s14"></td>
            <td id="td_s15"></td>
            <td id="td_s16"></td>
          </tr>

      </tbody>
      </table>
```

Comment: Are you calling the php file using an ajax call or you just want to generate the shown HTML ??

Comment: i want to generate the database value into the tbody of my table with button onclick do you know how to generate that?

Comment: Do you want to generate the headers also ??

Comment: nope just the value.. the value from my php function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate the HTML of `<tbody>` like this.

```
 if($array>0){
    $tableHTML = "<tbody>";
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $tableHTML .= "<tr>";
        $i=0;
        foreach ($row as $key=>$val) {
            $tableHTML .= "<td id='td_s".$i."'>".$row[$key]."</td>";
            $i++;
        }
        $tableHTML .= "</tr>";
    }   
    $tableHTML .= "<tbody>";
 }else{
    echo "<li>Tidak ada artikel yang ditemukan <li>";
 }
```

You will append the columns to each `<td>` to create the table.

Complete code

```
<form name="table_s" id="table_s" class="table_s">
<table id="table_s" class="table_s"cellspacing='0' class="js-serial" border="2">
    <thead>
  <tr>
            <th><center>No.</center></th>
            <th><center>S1</center></th>
            <th><center>S2</center></th>
            <th><center>S3</center></th>
            <th><center>S4</center></th>
            <th><center>S5</center></th>
            <th><center>S6</center></th>
            <th><center>S7</center></th>
            <th><center>S8</center></th>
            <th><center>S9</center></th>
            <th><center>S10</center></th>
            <th><center>S11</center></th>
            <th><center>S12</center></th>
            <th><center>Ambien</center></th>
            <th><center>Average</center></th>
            <th><center>Deff</center></th>
            <th><center>Status</center></th>
  </tr>

    </thead>
<?php
 $tableHTML = "";
 if($array>0){
    $tableHTML .= "<tbody>";
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $tableHTML .= "<tr>";
        $i=0;
        foreach ($row as $key=>$val) {
            $tableHTML .= "<td id='td_s".$i."'>".$row[$key]."</td>";
            $i++;
        }
        $tableHTML .= "</tr>";
    }   
    $tableHTML .= "<tbody>";
 } else{
    echo "<li>Tidak ada artikel yang ditemukan <li>";
 }

 echo $tableHTML; //echo the HTML of tbody

 ?>
  </table>
```

**Jquery Code**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#ok').on('click', function(e) {

      $.ajax({                                      
      url: '../php/termo_sel.php',                           
      data: {datepicker: 'val1', silo : 'val2'}, //Pass data to PHP by POST
      type: 'post',                       
      dataType: 'json',                     
      success: function(data)    //Whatever is put in echo in PHP is returned here     
      {
        $('#table_s').append(data);
      }
      });

    });
});
```

Just use this code. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `json_encode` on your array, you can access each column in your array by doing $array['column name']. For example if you have a users table with username and password and you need to get them you do `$array['username']` and `$array['password']`

Looking at your code it seems you want to display them one by one, in here:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<tr> $row['column name'] </tr>";
}
```

Comment: yeah like that.. i want to call them one by one but for all the record of the column.. but i want to call the value on the tbody that i made in my html(need on click function not a direct function) .

Comment: i just want to call the value from that php function can be filled in my html tbody table. can help me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<form name="table_s" id="table_s" class="table_s">
    <table id="table_s" class="table_s"cellspacing='0' class="js-serial" border="2">
        <thead>
      <tr>
                <th><center>No.</center></th>
                <th><center>S1</center></th>
                <th><center>S2</center></th>
                <th><center>S3</center></th>
                <th><center>S4</center></th>
                <th><center>S5</center></th>
                <th><center>S6</center></th>
                <th><center>S7</center></th>
                <th><center>S8</center></th>
                <th><center>S9</center></th>
                <th><center>S10</center></th>
                <th><center>S11</center></th>
                <th><center>S12</center></th>
                <th><center>Ambien</center></th>
                <th><center>Average</center></th>
                <th><center>Deff</center></th>
                <th><center>Status</center></th>
      </tr>

        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <?php do { ?>
          <tr>
            <td id="td_s0"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['no']; ?></td>
            <td id="td_s1"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['sensor1']; ?></td>
            <td id="td_s2"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['sensor2']; ?></td>
            <td id="td_s3"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['sensor3']; ?></td>
            <td id="td_s4"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['sensor4']; ?></td>
            <td id="td_s5"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['sensor5']; ?></td>
            <td id="td_s6"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['sensor6']; ?></td>
            <td id="td_s7"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['sensor7']; ?></td>
            <td id="td_s8"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['sensor8']; ?></td>
            <td id="td_s9"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['sensor9']; ?></td>
            <td id="td_s10"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['sensor10']; ?></td>
            <td id="td_s11"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['sensor11']; ?></td>
            <td id="td_s12"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['sensor12']; ?></td>
            <td id="td_s13"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['ambien']; ?></td>
            <td id="td_s14"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['average']; ?></td>
            <td id="td_s15"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['deffiasi']; ?></td>
            <td id="td_s16"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['status']; ?></td>
          </tr>
          <?php } while ($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1)); ?>
            </tr>
      </tbody>
      </table>
```

this is what i mean.. the tbody of my table has a value of a record.
can i just places the echo of your edited script inside them again or can i place the echo inside the jquery?

Answer (score 0):

JQUERY CODE

```js
$(document).on('click','#ok',function(e) {

    $.ajax({                                      
      url: '../php/termo_sel.php',                           
      data: "",                        
      dataType: 'json',                     
      success: function(data)         
      {
        var id = data[0];             
        var tanggal = data[1];
        var silo = data[2];
        var sensor1 = data[3];
        var sensor2 = data[4];
        var sensor3 = data[5];
        var sensor4 = data[6];
        var sensor5 = data[7];
        var sensor6 = data[8];
        var sensor7 = data[9];
        var sensor8 = data[10];
        var sensor9 = data[11];
        var sensor10= data[12];
        var ambien= data[13];
        var average= data[14];
        var deffiasi= data[15];
        var status= data[16];

        $('#data_area').html("<b></b>"+id+"<b></b>"+tanggal); //Set output element html
        //recommend reading up on jquery selectors they are awesome 
        // http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/
      }
    });

    clearInput();

});

function clearInput() {
    $("#form_input :input").each( function() {
       $('#s1').val('');
       $('#s2').val('');
       $('#s3').val('');
       $('#s4').val('');
       $('#s5').val('');
       $('#s6').val('');
       $('#s7').val('');
       $('#s8').val('');
       $('#s9').val('');
       $('#s10').val('');
       $('#s11').val('');
       $('#s12').val('');
       $('#amb').val('35.0');
       $('#avr').val('');
       $('#deff').val('');
       $('#sts').val('');
    });


}
```

HTML CODE

```
<div id="kanan"  class="btn btn-default" style="padding-left:20px" >
    <form name="table_s" id="table_s" class="table_s">
    <table id="table_s" class="table_s"cellspacing='0' class="js-serial" border="2">
        <thead>

      <tr>
                <th><center>No.</center></th>
                <th><center>S1</center></th>
                <th><center>S2</center></th>
                <th><center>S3</center></th>
                <th><center>S4</center></th>
                <th><center>S5</center></th>
                <th><center>S6</center></th>
                <th><center>S7</center></th>
                <th><center>S8</center></th>
                <th><center>S9</center></th>
                <th><center>S10</center></th>
                <th><center>S11</center></th>
                <th><center>S12</center></th>
                <th><center>Ambien</center></th>
                <th><center>Average</center></th>
                <th><center>Deff</center></th>
                <th><center>Status</center></th>
      </tr>

        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <?php do { ?>
          <tr>
            <td id="td_s0"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['no']; ?></td>
            <td id="td_s1"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['sensor1']; ?></td>
            <td id="td_s2"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['sensor2']; ?></td>
            <td id="td_s3"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['sensor3']; ?></td>
            <td id="td_s4"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['sensor4']; ?></td>
            <td id="td_s5"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['sensor5']; ?></td>
            <td id="td_s6"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['sensor6']; ?></td>
            <td id="td_s7"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['sensor7']; ?></td>
            <td id="td_s8"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['sensor8']; ?></td>
            <td id="td_s9"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['sensor9']; ?></td>
            <td id="td_s10"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['sensor10']; ?></td>
            <td id="td_s11"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['sensor11']; ?></td>
            <td id="td_s12"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['sensor12']; ?></td>
            <td id="td_s13"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['ambien']; ?></td>
            <td id="td_s14"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['average']; ?></td>
            <td id="td_s15"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['deffiasi']; ?></td>
            <td id="td_s16"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['status']; ?></td>
          </tr>
          <?php } while ($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1)); ?>
            </tr>
      </tbody>
      </table>
```

PHP CODE

```
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // Example php script for fetching data from mysql database
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $host = "localhost";
  $user = "root";
  $pass = "";

  $databaseName = "silo";
  $tableName = "temp1";

  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // 1) Connect to mysql database
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------

  $con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
  $dbs = mysql_select_db($databaseName, $con);

  $tanggal=$_POST['datepicker'];
  $silo=$_POST['silo'];
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // 2) Query database for data
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tableName");          //query
  $array = mysql_fetch_row($result);                          //fetch result 

  if($array>0){
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    }   
 }else{
    echo "<li>Tidak ada artikel yang ditemukan <li>";
 }
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // 3) echo result as json 
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  echo json_encode($array);

?>
```

three of them separate in 3 file. .php, .html, .js